# EntityManager createQuery with single column throws type error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

I am using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `OracleUCPConfig`

I have class `EmployeeEntity.java` mapped to table employee

I have written a `createQuery` code as

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select id from Employee", EmployeeEntity.class);
query.getResultList()
```

I am getting error as:

```
Type specified for TypedQuery [EmployeeEntity] is incompatible with [java.lang.String]
```

how do I solve this issue?

I want all ids from the table not any other fields needs to retrieved

--EDIT--

I solved the issue by change the JQL to JPQL

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select new EmployeeEntity(id) from Employee", EmployeeEntity.class);
query.getResultList()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of scenario requires an EmployeeEntity that is made of a single field that is a string id of another entity ?

Answer (score 0):

you are mapping `id` to type `EmployeeEntity`, if you check your query, you are extracting only `id` instead of everything: `select id from Employee`. you can fix this by changing your query to:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e", EmployeeEntity.class);
```

if you need only id column you could do something like:

```
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery("select e.id from Employee e", String.class);
List<String> ids = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: true, but I want all ids from the table not any other fields needs to retrieved

Comment: @DickensAS if you want to have it in one like, you could do `List<String> ids = em.createQuery("select e.id from Employee e", String.class).getResultList();`

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [createQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) is the type of the query result. In your case, the result type is `String` (a list of `String`s), as you only `SELECT` the column `id`.

So this should work:

```java
Query query = em.createQuery("select e.id from Employee e", String.class);
List<String> ids = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: you mean to say, I need to write another for loop to form EmployeeEntity as service result, doesn't spring offer such facility ?

Comment: No, I updated my answer with the correct query selecting only the `id` field

Comment: As per your question, you "want all ids from the table not any other fields needs to retrieved". If you want a list with entities, use `Query query = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e", EmployeeEntity.class)`

Comment: I changed the query to JPQL which solves my problem without writing another code to transform List<String> to List<EmployeeEntity> technically I don't want another loop